# How to pass arguments to both inner and outer function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, currying

I have a function that returns another function. I need to pass arguments to both functions. When I try to do that, I can only pass one argument and not two. How do I pass two arguments to validatorRegex?

```
export const validatorRegex = (regex: RegExp | RegExp[]) => (value: string) =>
  Array.isArray(regex) ? regex.every((rx) => rx.test(value)) : regex.test(value);
```

Comment: validatorRegex expects only one parameter and returns another function expecting one more parameter, so `validatorRegex(/test/)('test')`

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`validatorRegex` is what is called a [curried](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function. Instead of taking two arguments, it takes one argument and returns a function that takes the other argument. You can call it like this:

```
validatorRegex(/foo/)('bar')
```

This is short for:

```
const f = validatorRegex(/foo/)
f('bar')
```